# Using Alexa to query a database

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit

How to query a database using ASK ? I want something like "Hey, Alexa get me the ID numbers of cars whose color is Red and type is Convertible" It should hit my database and get all the corresponding records. Is talking to database using Alexa possible ? If yes, than how ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should understand that the skill consist of 2 parts.

- The "amazon alexa skill service" which you configure with your intents and slots via the [alexa developer console](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask)
- your HTTP REST backend which consist of all the logic and responds to the users. Here you can also call external services (websites, databases) whatever you want.

  - to ease the usage for this defined interfaces Amazon developed some SDKs, eg. for [python](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-python/overview.html)
  - you can run your python code on a webserver or as amazon lambda service. Here you can make your calls to the database. E.g. you could use the amazon [dynamo db](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.html).

Best would be to read in general about [custom skills](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/understanding-custom-skills.html) and afterwards dig deeper with the links above.